# Running a python based command line script as cronjob on gcloud

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, cron, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I have a python3 based command line script which does the job of report generation for services running online. I am able to successfully schedule it as a cronjob using crontab and some shell script to run that script on weekly basis. 
But now, I wish to update and make this script run as a cronjob on gcloud.
Can you provide me any ideas or references, from where I will be able to achieve that?

Note that platform is restricted to google cloud only.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [App Engine Cron Service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron):

> The App Engine Cron Service allows you to configure regularly
>   scheduled tasks that operate at defined times or regular intervals.
>   These tasks are commonly known as cron jobs. These cron jobs are
>   automatically triggered by the App Engine Cron Service. For instance,
>   you might use a cron job to send out an email report on a daily basis,
>   or to update some cached data every 10 minutes, or refresh summary
>   information once an hour.

Create a service like `/tasks/summary` and schedule it to run each week Monday morning via [cron.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref):

```
cron:
- description: weekly summary job
  url: /tasks/summary
  target: beta
  schedule: every monday 09:00
```